# Factorygirl create complex collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have an Item and Category. I want to have multiple Items, each with multiple Categories. I don't want each Item to have different Categories, but rather associate with a common set of Categories.

Is there a way to achieve this using the FactoryGirl dsl?

Here is how I did it using a helper module:

```
module Features
  module ItemsHelpers
    def create_items_with_categories
      parents = create_list :category, 2
      children = []
      5.times do
        children << (create :category, parent: parents.sample)
      end
      10.times do
        item = build :item
        item.categories << children.sample(3)
        item.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the code, I assume, item has many categories:

```
sequence :name do |n|
  "Item - #{n}"
end

factory :item do
  name { generate(:name) }
  # other fields here..
  ignore do # in the latest version, it is: "transient do.."
    categories_count 5
  end

  after(:create) do |item, evaluator|
    categories { FactoryGirl.create_list(:category, evaluator.categories_count) }
  end
end
```

You can use this as:

```
  let(:categories) { create_list(:category, 10) }
  let(:items) { create_list(:item, 5, categories: categories) }
```

UPDATE: In many cases, when your specs grow, you won't have to be bothered about adding extra: `categories` while creating `items` as it'll be created by the default values, unless specified. Hence, ignore/ transient for keeping it classy.

So you can do:

```
let(:items) { create_list(:items, 10, categories_count: 3) } # when you need just 3 categories per item!!
```

At the end, it comes down to the preference and the coding structure you follow. I prefer to have both so that I don't have to bother adding `categories` list when cretaing `item` or `items` factory.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the code. Why not just do what you offered in the "You can use this as" section without all the other stuff? You're just creating a list of categories, then associating them with each item when you create your list of items. So in this case, each item would have the same categories. So why do the transient/ignore and after create callback in the factory?

Comment: But will each item be generating different categories for itself, or the same 3 categories will be used be each item?

Comment: In the first case, same categories will be reused/same, in latter case new categories will be generated for every item.